# Motherboard won't boot up properly unless I heat it up with hair dryer. What component can be faulty?

Tags: boot, motherboard, chipset, asus

PC Motherboard - Asus P5B, CPU - Intel q6600. Out of the case, only with processor left and power supply connected, won't produce beep signals when turning on, fan spinning idly. Checked with another power supply. Only when I heat motherboard up with hair dryer directed on a chipset, it boots up, and signals that video card is missing (as it should). I need to make sure here what component exactly is faulty, and how I can fix it.

P.S. With all the other elements assembled back, booted up with this hair dryer method, pc works fine for hours.

P.S.S. Since the trouble is occurring only when turning it on, and it works fine for hours, to what components can we narrow it down? I believe some capacitors are only involved in starting up

Comment: I would make a cone from a piece of paper and fasten to the hair dryer outlet to get a better, more directed stream of hot air to aim directly at a component. See if you can narrow it down that way. It could be a cold solder joint on the board near / underneath the component.  Continued running provides the necessary heat.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea, I'll try it out

Comment: I hope you understand this method won’t work forever

Comment: My posted idea is to find the issue. You are correct that it is not a way to make the system run reliably. Finding the part or connection is what is needed.

Comment: As I already told you on your other (deleted) question "Take it to a repair shop and get a proper diagnosis."

Comment: have u tried replace cmos battery and then doing a clear cmos reset? if u have the motherboard manual u can find a section where is explained.

Comment: Yes I tried that, doesn't work